# Splitting an unspaced string of decimal values - Python

Tags: python, string, list, split, delimiter

An awful person has given me a string like this

```
values = '.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'
```

and I need to split it to create the following list:

```
['.850000', '.900000', '.950000', '1.00000', '1.500000']
```

I know that I was dealing only with numbers < 1 I could use the code

```
dl = '.' 
splitvalues = [dl+e for e in values.split(dl) if e != ""]
```

But in cases like this one where there are numbers greater than 1 buried in the string, splitvalue would end up being

```
['.850000', '.900000', '.9500001', '.000001', '.50000']
```

So is there a way to split a string with multiple delimiters while also splitting the string differently based on which delimiter is encountered?

Comment: Do all the numbers end with 0 or is there some way to know when the number ends?

Comment: Is that third number in the string correct, or did you type one too many digits?

Comment: There is no way to know where to start and end splitting. For example is `0.850000.900000` = `[0.85, 0.9]` or `[0.8, 50000.9]`?

Comment: do all the number have the same precision?  From your example it doesn't appear so.

Comment: `0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'.match(/[1-9]?\.\d{5}0?/g)` 
`[".850000", ".900000", ".950000", "1.00000", "1.50000"]`

Comment: You slip of the pen.  It should be one of `'.860000'` and `0.850000`.

Comment: Another error in your question. The result of your code is `['.0', '.850000', '.900000', '.9500001', '.000001', '.50000']`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sorry for the typos, they've been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> source = '0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'

>>> re.findall("(.*?00+(?!=0))", source)

['0.850000', '.900000', '.950000', '1.00000', '1.50000']
```

The split is based on looking for "*{anything, double zero, a run of zeros (followed by a not-zero)*"}.

Comment: This works great. I was sure I was going to have to use a complicated list comprehension with ors and nots.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is somewhat closer to a fixed width format string. Try a regular expression like this:

```
import re

str = "(\d{1,2}\\.\d{5})"
m = re.search(str, input_str)
your_first_number = m.group(0)
```

Try this repeatedly on the remaining string to consume all numbers.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find'`

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the value before the decimal is less than 10, and then we have,

```
values = '0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'

result = list()
last_digit = None 

for value in values.split('.'):
    if value.endswith('0'):
        result.append(''.join([i for i in [last_digit, '.', value] if i]))
        last_digit = None
    else:
        result.append(''.join([i for i in [last_digit, '.', value[0:-1]] if i]))
        last_digit = value[-1]

if values.startswith('0'):
    result = result[1:]

print(result)
# Output
['.850000', '.900000', '.950000', '1.00000', '1.50000']
```

Answer (score 1):

With a fixed / variable string, you may try something like:

```
values = '0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'
str_list = []

first_index = values.find('.')
while first_index > 0:
    last_index = values.find('.', first_index + 1)
    if last_index != -1:
        str_list.append(values[first_index - 1: last_index - 2])
        first_index = last_index
    else:
        str_list.append(values[first_index - 1: len(values) - 1])
        break
print str_list
```

> Output:
>
> ['0.8500', '0.9000', '0.95000', '1.0000', '1.5000']
>
> Assuming that there will always be a single digit before the decimal.
>
> Please take this as a starting point and not a copy paste solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `re.split()`:

```
import re

values = '0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'

print([a + b for a, b in zip(*(lambda x: (x[1::2], x[2::2]))(re.split(r"(\d\.)", values)))])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['0.85000', '0.90000', '0.950000', '1.00000', '1.50000']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here digits are of fixed width, i.e. 6, if include the dot it's 7. Get the slices from 0 to 7 and 7 to 14 and so on. Because we don't need the initial zero, I use the slice `values[1:]` for extraction.

```
values = '0.850000.900000.9500001.000001.50000'
[values[1:][start:start+7] for start in range(0,len(values[1:]),7)]
['.850000', '.900000', '.950000', '1.00000', '1.50000']
```

Test;

```
''.join([values[1:][start:start+7] for start in range(0,len(values[1:]),7)]) == values[1:]
True
```